How many natural numbers less than $10,000$ have digit sum equal to $15$?
Suppose we want to know the number of natural numbers less than $10,000$ where the digit sum is equal to $9$. These natural numbers look like $ABCD$ for $A,B,C,D = 0,1,2, \ldots 9$ and the number is valid iff $A+B+C+D=9$. The formula for the number of nonnegative integer solutions $(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_k)$ to $x_1+x_2 + \ldots + x_k = n$ is well known to equal to ${n+k-1} \choose {k-1}$. Hence there are $12 \choose 3$ valid natural numbers.
Now suppose we want to know the number of natural numbers less than $10,000$ where the digit sum is equal to $15$. This time there is no correspondence between the solutions $(A,B,C,D)$ to $A+B+C+D = 15$ because for example the solution $(15,0,0,0)$ does nto correspond to a natural number. What we are interested this time is the number of nonnegative integer solutions $(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_k)$ to $x_1+x_2 + \ldots + x_k = N$ with all $n_i \le n$.
How would one approach such a problem?

Your start is fine,  to finish just note that no  $4-$tuple can have more than one entry which is $10$ or more,  so just count those separately.

For sake of definitiveness, a brute-force search with Mathematica gives 592 such numbers.

Agree with the comment of lulu.  For a general discussion, see this answer
for a blueprint of how to combine Inclusion-Exclusion with Stars-And-Bars to
attack this generic type of problem.

This is classically done with inclusion-exclusion, or with generating functions.

Specifically, it is the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $$\dfrac{(1-x^{10})^4}{(1-x)^4}$$

You get $\binom{15+3}3-4\binom{5+3}3$
